# How to retriew values from NSDictionary?

Tags: ios6, nsdictionary

I have a `NSDictionary` like this

```
`(
    {
    EmployeeCode = 7593;
    InDate = "27/02/2013";
    InTime = "08:11";
    InTime2 = "00:00";
    OutDate = "27/02/2013";
    OutDate2 = "01/01/1901";
    OutTime = "17:42";
    OutTime2 = "00:00";
    Present = 1;
}
```

)

`Then I want to retriew values from this. So I put`NSLog`

```
` NSLog(@"TESTING---------- %@",[dicDates valueForKey:@"OutDate"] );`
```

But the value displays with brackets

`TESTING---------- (
    "27/02/2013"`

What is the reason for that. Plz help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling a wrong method: instead of `valueForKey:` you need to call `objectForKey:`.

The `valueForKey:` method is for [*key-value coding*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html), while `objectForKey:` is for retrieving objects through the associative mapping provided by `NSDictionary`.

Comment: thanks for commenting, But it gives an error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x711b680'
`

Comment: @saji723 This means that you've got an `NSArray`, not an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: I got it into a NSArray, Now my `dicDates` is a NSArray. But it still gives that error. If I put valueForKey it not gives that error but retriew values with brackets. Why is that?

Comment: @saji723 You cannot retrieve objects from `NSArray` by key, because it is not an associative container. You need to use `objectAtIndex:...` to retrieve values from it.